# Prevent Case Close with Open Tasks

Tags: validation

We need an error whenever a case is closed but there are remaining open tasks not completed.  Is there any easy way of doing this?  Also, is it possible to update a date field in the CASE based on the date a specific activity is closed?

Comment: I think you will have to go for a trigger .Looks like no shortcut or out of box stuff

Answer (score 9):

I agree with @Monith Kumar.  I think you'll need a trigger.  You could do something where you count the number of non closed Tasks for Cases that are being saved with their IsClosed changing from false to true.  Just keep in mind that triggers need to be written to handle bulk updates, so you have to assume that more than one Case is being updated in the Trigger.  Here's a rough idea to get you started.

```
trigger CaseTrigger on Case (after update) {

    // Find all cases that are being closed...
    Set<Id> newlyClosedCaseIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (Id caseId : Trigger.newMap.keySet()) {
        if (Trigger.newMap.get(caseId).IsClosed && 
            !Trigger.oldMap.get(caseId).IsClosed) {
            newlyClosedCaseIds.add(caseId);
        }
    }

    // For every newly closed Case that has at least one 
    // not closed task add an error to the Trigger.newMap entry.
    // Adding the error to the Trigger.new entry will prevent the save
    // and add the error message to the page messages that get displayed on
    // the page.
    for (AggregateResult aggResult : [
            Select Count(Id), WhatId
            From Task
            Where WhatId In :newlyClosedCaseIds
                  And IsClosed = false
            Group by WhatId
            Having Count(Id) > 0
    ]) {
        Id caseId = (Id) aggResult.get('WhatId');
        Case errorCase = Trigger.newMap.get(caseId);

        // change error message as appropriate...
        errorCase.addError('Cannot close case since there are non closed tasks: ' +
                           errorCase.SuppliedName); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To answer second part of your question; "Also, is it possible to update a date field in the CASE based on the date a specific activity is closed?" , you can create a Cross Object Workflow to do that.

1. Create a Workflow Rule on the "activity" object.
2. Associate a field update with this workflow rule to update whichever date field (or any other) you want to update on Case object.

Comment: +1. Theoretically cross object workflows could be used to increment some hidden counter up & down as tasks are opened & closed (it would fail when you delete a Task though).

Comment: @eyescream - you can click the little up-arrow thingie rather than putting '+1' in a comment :-)

Comment: I blame my annoying wifi. Thx @metadaddy

Answer (score 0):

A Better computation Solution:  Below code I used Case With  Open Task (Standard Object). You can try with any Combination of Standard or Custom Objects.

```
trigger caseTigger on Case (before update) {

    Set<Id> csids = new Set<Id>();
    for(Case cs : Trigger.new){
        if(cs.status=='Closed'){
            csids.add(cs.Id);
        }
    }

    for(AggregateResult agg : [select count(Id), WhatId from Task where whatId in :csids and Status != 'Completed' group by WhatId]){
        if( Integer.valueof(agg.get('expr0')) > 0){
           Case tskrcrd = Trigger.newMAp.get(String.valueOf(agg.get('whatId')));
           tskrcrd.addError('You cant close the case, as there is an Open task ');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide profiling information to back up the suggestion that this is computationally better?